# How can i go back to history while maintaining scroll position and state in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-state

In what way can i achieve this? [sample gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfSSu.gif)

Please help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The image-view component is drawn over the search results, which basically covers the whole screen. Once you close it, you see the search results again hidden beneath it.

To make it work on browser back you can push a query param in url(let's say it's `/myUrl`) when the image is clicked

```
 props.history.push({
      pathname: props.match.path,
      search: `?galleryView=${imageId}`
  });
```

This will change `/myUrl` to `/myUrl/?galleryView=123`.

When browser back is clicked, it'll go back to previous url i.e. `/myUrl`. And you'd need to close the gallery overlay.

To do that, In your component's `componentDidUpdate` method you can check if `props.match.params` have changed and if `galleryView` query param was removed, then close the gallery overlay.

```
if(prevProps.match.params.galleryView && !this.props.match.params.galleryView) {
 this.closeGalleryOverlay();
}
```

You'll also need to handle the case when user directly comes to this url `/myUrl/?galleryView=123`, basically you'd have to open the gallery overlay then.

Comment: I already tried that way but when i press the back button, the image view did not closed. Instead, i was redirected back to my browser history.

Comment: I really appreciate your response man. By pushing `props.history.push({
      pathname: props.match.path,
      search: `?galleryView=${imageId}`
  });` to history will now reset the scroll position and states when i press the back button.